# PHP MySQL INSERT statement syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm having problems with an INSERT statement, and the error only says:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

It's not helpful at all.
The version I have tried so far and failed is:

```
mysql_query("INSET INTO `cos` VALUES ('".$_GET['prod']."','".$_GET['page']."')");
```

[needless to say that the two variables when printed show the right values]
I've also tried versions with nothing around the table name, with ` or ', a million combinations really and nothing works. Not even with constants or into different tables. It just won't insert anything ever. I've checked the privileges (I'm logging into it with root), and it's all on.

I've tried similar stuff on two different machines with the same server (XAMPP 1.7.7) and it works. I'm completely baffled! What can it be?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, just type `INSERT` correctly.

Using `_GET` like that really opens you up to SQL INJECTIONS...

Do take a look into [MySQL prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

It is also considered *good practice* to name the columns that you're inserting data into. That allows you to, latter on, insert extra-columns and keep application logic.

```
INSERT INTO cos(rowName1, rowName2) VALUES(?, ?)
```

Where `?` would be prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

Correct:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cos` VALUES ('".$_GET['prod']."','".$_GET['page']."')");
```

Have you tried passing the $link to `mysql_query` ?

Like:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cos` VALUES ('".$_GET['prod']."','".$_GET['page']."')", $link);
```

EDIT:
And of course you must take some security measures before inserting anything into the database, maybe `mysql_real_escape_string()` or even prepared statements.

Comment: You should point out that someone should never ever use user defined parameters directly in SQL statements.

Comment: @FloIancu If that solved your problem, click the check mark near the number on the left of my post.

Comment: Every one makes mistake! and did you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. Why aren't you escaping the values? 
Php.net documentation is providing some good and safe working examples:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT firstname, lastname, address, age FROM friends 
    WHERE firstname='%s' AND lastname='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($firstname),
    mysql_real_escape_string($lastname));

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

So adapted to your code:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `cos` VALUES (%s, %s);", 
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['prod']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Please, always escape your values. And use INSERT, not INSET :)

Answer (score 0):

first this is you are using `INSET` make it correct with `INSERT` like

```
$pro = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['prod']);
$page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cos` (column1, column2)
             VALUES ('$pro', '$page')" );
```

you forget to set the column names...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$prod = $_GET['prod'];
$page = $_GET['page'];
mysql_insert("INSERT INTO 'cos' VALUES('$prod','$page)");
```

This should very well do it :)